# Antiblocking equivalent to Distributivity in Lattices

Tags: alternative-proof, lattice-orders

Let as say that a lattice $L$ has the anti-blocking property if for all $a,b,x\in L$  such that $a \nleq b$, $a \nleq x$ and $x \nleq b$, either $a \nleq x \vee b$ or $a \wedge x \nleq b$ holds.
The intuition behind it, is that if I have $a \nleq b$, and I have some $x$ not greater than $a$
and not smaller than $b$, I can either increase $b$, or decrease $a$, with either $b' :=  x \vee b$ or $a' := a \wedge x$, and thus having either $a' \nleq b$ or $a \nleq b'$

The goal is to show that **A lattice is distributive if and only if it has the anti-blocking property**.

Left to right implication follows easily by assuming is not true and using
the distributive laws to get a contradiction. However, the other direction seems a little bit harder. I have proved
it (I think), but the proof is not so simple.

My questions is the following then, how can we prove this, that **every lattice with the anti-blocking property is distributive**? Maybe some of you know a simple proof of this fact, or it is interested in finding one. Thanks anyway!.

PD: Should I show my proof also? If so, should I post that as an answer, or edit this?

edit: I did not mentioned it, but I'm thinking on a proof not using (directly) the fact that a lattice is distributive iff does not have M3 or N5 as a sublattice.

Comment: This might be one of those goods cases in which the characterization of distributive lattices as those which don't have either $N_5$ or $M_3$ as sub-lattice is specially useful. Indeed, it's very easy to see that neither of those have the property, but I don't see how to prove it otherwise. It's certainly possible, but why should we care?

Comment: I have no good reasons really. I was looking for a simple proof. And using that lemma Is not what I consider simple. That's because to use it here you would have to proof the "hard" implication, which is "if there is no copy of N5 or M3, L is distributive".

Comment: I understand. Maybe that's one of the reasons for which that result is so important. And perhaps its proof it's not even harder than the one you're searching for

Comment: Yep that might as well be the case. Thanks.